# Overflow error in c to find prime factors of a twelve-digit number

Tags: c, primes, integer-overflow, prime-factoring

I want to solve this problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=3 by this program, but I'm not sure its true way to use long long int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long long int result = factors(6051475143);
    printf("%lld", result); 
    return 0;
}

void factors(int number) {
    int factor[100000];
    int index = 0, i = 1;
    for (; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            factor[index] = i;
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    findprime(factor, 100000);
}

int findprime(int prime[], int size) {
    int i = 0, j;
    long long int latestprime;
    for(; i < size; i++) {
        if (prime[i] == 0)
            break;
        int is_prime = 1;
        for (j = 2; j < prime[i]; j++) {
            if (prime[i] % j == 0 && prime[i] != j) {   
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_prime == 1)
            latestprime = prime[i];
    } 
    return latestprime;
}
```

If I try 10-digit number it works but when I try a 12-digit number it returns zero.

Comment: Try passing strict options to your compiler (like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and it will probably give you some relevant clues.

Comment: Also `-Wconversion` or just use `-Weverything` if you are using Clang

Comment: The `factors` function is implemented as a `void` function, but you use it's (non existent) return value. What is `factors` supposed to do?

Comment: `6051475143` does not fit in a 32-bit integer. Try changing your data types from `int` to `long long int`.

Comment: `if (prime[i] == 0)` You never assign `0` to any element of the array.

Comment: `findprime(factor,100000);` Why not pass the number of found factors `index` instead of array size? BTW: What happens if you find more than 100000 factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, you indeed need a type that is large enough to represent the number. `unsigned long long` is specified as having at least 64 value bits, which is `18446744073709551615`.

Your program has **undefined behavior**, even for small numbers: `result = factors(6051475143)` does not reliably store anything useful as `factors` is defined as a `void` function and does not even have a `return` statement. It works by chance because the last statement, `findprime(factor, 100000);` leaves the return value of `findprime` in the register where `main` retrieves what it expects to be the `int` result of `factors()`, an return type inferred by the compiler from the lack of prototype.

To find the largest prime factor, you should try factors and reduce the number whenever you find one that divides it evenly.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long largest_factor(unsigned long long number) {
    unsigned long long p;
    if (number < 2)
        return number;
    for (p = 2; p * p <= number; p++) {
        while (number % p == 0) {
            number /= p;
        }
    }
    if (number == 1)
        return p;
    else
        return number;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%llu\n", largest_factor(6051475143)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a few changes in my code and I I added the condition that p * p is less than the number and I find solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

long long int result =factors(6051475143);
printf("%lld",result); 
return 0;
}

factors(long long int number)
{
    long int factor[1000000];
    long long int x;
    long int index=0,i=1;
    for(;i<800000; i++)
    {
        if (number%i==0)
        {
            factor[index] = i;
            index+=1;
        
        }
    }
    x = findprime(factor,index);
    return x;
}

int findprime(long int prime[],long int size)
{
    long int i = 0,j;
    long long int latestprime;
    for(;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (prime[i] == 0)
            break;
        int is_prime=1;
        for(j=2;j<prime[i];j++)
        {
            if (prime[i]%j==0 && prime[i]!=j)
            {   
                is_prime=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_prime==1)
            latestprime = prime[i];
    } 
    return latestprime;
}
```

Comment: I made some edits to your code, else it would have ran for quite an amount of time:

Comment: The loop `for(;i<800000; i++)` will not find prime factors larger than 800000.

Comment: Every positive integer n has at least one prime factor less than sqrt(n). That's why I used a bound, because if p|n(that's p divides n) , then p/n divides n